# Find the Minimum and Maximun of ListDensityPlot in Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization, plotting

I have a set of data points, lets say {x_i,y_i,A_i}. I want to find the Minimum and Maximum value of A_i from a ListDensityPlot in Mathematica. Along with the corresponding x_i & y_i values.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: Can you give some example code to show us what you have tried, or even based on what you are trying to do? This will make it much easier for others to answer your question

Comment: I see no change to reconstruct original function values from a given densityplot. see: `f[x_] := x^2 + y^2 + 1
data = Table[{x, y, f[x]/2}, {x, -5, 5, 1}, {y, -5, 5, 1}] // N; ldp = ListDensityPlot@Flatten[data, 1]; ldp // FullForm `

Answer (score 1):

Use `Max` and `Min`:

```
    f[x_] := x^2 + y^2
    data = Table[{x, y, f[x]}, {x, -5, 5, .1}, {y, -5, 5, .1}]
    datamax = Max[Map[#[[3]] &, Flatten[data, 1]]]
    datamin = Min[Map[#[[3]] &, Flatten[data, 1]]]
```

Comment: It's even shorter if you do `MinMax[data[[All, All, 3]]]` and get the points themselves with `MaximalBy[Flatten[data, 1], Last]` and `MinimalBy[Flatten[data, 1], Last]`